# Download all objects from S3 Bucket and send content to SQS

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am using python boto3 to get all the objects in a bucket but it returns the keys and not the content

I have a service which reads messages from SQS (a duplicate message is also present in s3 bucket) and does some operations. I have lost some sqs messages because of some failures and sqs 14 day policy.

The files have json data, with each file ranging from 4-8kb.

Now I want to re-drive all the objects from s3 to SQS.

Is there a way to get content of all files and then transfer them to SQS ?

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer them to SQS"? Why do you wish to put the content of objects into SQS — are they text files, images, binary files? What if they are big objects? Feel free to edit your question to provide more information and we will be able to offer better advice.

Comment: I used s3 as a backup for the sqs messages. Because of some failure in sqs poller service and downtime , sqs messages are lost , now i want to redrive the messages from s3 to queue

Comment: Oh! In that case, you will have to write something yourself, probably in the same way that you stored it in the first place. There is no automated method to move data from S3 to SQS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein)'s comment into an answer:

*Is there a way to get content of all files and then transfer them to SQS ?*

No. You will have to write something yourself, probably in the same way that you stored it in the first place. There is no automated method to move data from S3 to SQS